# Multiplying vector by scalar in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to multiply a vector by scalar quantity, but I'm getting an

> Error:expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have pointer to function type

What does this mean?
Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<double>propenisty_fun;
    double rate_const;
    vector<int>X; 

    X.push_back(10);
    X.push_back(0);
    X.push_back(12);
    X.push_back(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter rate_constant :" << endl;
        cin >> rate_const;
        propenisty_fun[i] = rate_const*0.5*X[i](X[i] - 1);
        cout<<propenisty_fun[i];
    } 
}
```

Comment: You forgot a multilication operator in front of the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with this line of code

```
propenisty_fun[i] = rate_const*0.5*X[i](X[i] - 1);
```

It should be `propenisty_fun[i] = rate_const*0.5*X[i]*(X[i] - 1);`